# BigDecimal.pow() of negative number

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponentiation

I just cannot find the correct answer, so here is my problem: I want to be able to calculate the indexation (*a positive or negative percentage*) over a `price` and `period`.

**Expectations:**

---

**Case #1**
Price : **1.000,00**
Indexation percentage : **5%**

Calculation over 5 years with positive percentage:

```
1. 1000 x 5^0 = 1000
2. 1000 x 5^1 = 1050
3. 1000 x 5^2 = 1102,50
4. 1000 x 5^3 = 1157.625
5. 1000 x 5^4 = 1215,50625
```

**Case #2**
Price : **1.000,00**
Indexation percentage : **-5%**

Calculation over 5 years with negative percentage:

```
1. 1000 x -5^0 = 1000
2. 1000 x -5^1 = 950
3. 1000 x -5^2 = 902,50
4. 1000 x -5^3 = 857,375
5. 1000 x -5^4 = 814,50625
```

**Results:**

---

And this negative percentage goes wrong, because my java code prints this out:

```
1000
-5000
-125000
15625000
1175690408
```

My code is pretty simple, i  think:

```
BigDecimal percentageValue = new BigDecimal("-5");
BigDecimal indexation = percentageValue.divide(ONE_HUNDRED).add(BigDecimal.ONE);
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("1000");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  price = price.multiply(indexation.pow(i));
  System.out.println(price.intValue());
}
```

**Solution:**

```
static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal("100");
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 BigDecimal percentageValue = new BigDecimal("-5");
 BigDecimal indexation = percentageValue.divide(ONE_HUNDRED).add(BigDecimal.ONE);
 BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("1000");

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
   BigDecimal result = price.multiply(indexation.pow(i));
   System.out.println(result);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply by `1 + percents/100`, 1% is 1/100.

Note that 5% intrest over one years makes 1000 become 1050 and not 5000

so for 5%: `1.05^n` and for negative [-5%]: `0.95^n`

You can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to do it, since the numebrs are not integers.

**EDIT: [as respond to editted question]** Your editted code does not produce the output you gave [assuming `ONE_HUNDRED` is initialized properly], however it still has a new issue:

```
  price = price.multiply(indexation.pow(i));
  System.out.println(price.intValue());
```

look at the second iteration, you already set `price = price * indexation^1`

When you multiply it again with `indexation^i` [i==2] you get a wrong result!

A solution could be one of those:

1. no need to `pow()` here, just multiply each iteration with the indexation.
2. Do not override `price`, hold the result of `price.multiply(indexation.pow(i)` in a new temp variable - and print it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the code where I collect my percentage value: percentageValue.divide(ONE_HUNDRED).add(BigDecimal.ONE)

Comment: @adis: The code does not behave how you described it now [assuming `ONE_HUNDRED` is defined properly], but there is yet another issue with your code - look at my edit for details.